# If statement what is wrong with my formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

What is wrong with this formula?

```
=IF(I89="Pepsi Direct","15 or 225$ Rev",
 IF(H89="Large Format",VLOOKUP(B89,LF_List,3,FALSE),
 IF(H89="Small Format",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B89,OTS_List,2,FALSE)),"22",
 IF(H89="FoodService Format","-",""))))
```

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Too many arguments

Comment: Yep, it's the `IF(H89....` statement that is causing the problem. You will need to review your formula and make appropriate changes. I can't fix it for you without the full sheet.

Comment: `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B89,OTS_List,2,FALSE)),"22"` should be `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B89,OTS_List,2,FALSE),"22")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Ahh, yes. That would work.

Answer (score 2):

You have too many arguments in one of the IF statements.

I've modified your question to make it easier to view, and now it's easy to see that there is an extra argument on `line 3`, the `,"22",` is a `false condition` and should have a close bracket after it.

You will need to refactor your formula somewhere, probably by moving the `"22"` and the final `IF` around to create another nested `IF`. Or put the bracket on the outside of the `"22"` like Scott suggested in his comment.

Comment: The bracket on the outside works.                                           =IF(I89="Pepsi Direct","15 or 225$ Rev",                                   IF(H89="Large Format",VLOOKUP(B89,LF_List,3,FALSE), IF(H89="Small Format",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B89,OTS_List,2,FALSE),"22"),
 IF(H89="FoodService Format","-",""))))

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of seeing what you're doing wrong is by substitution.  Try using something like "True and False" substitution method in my example, it works for me almost every-time.. Anyhow this is the solution I believe, it was also mentioned above in many other examples. Good luck.

```
=IF(I89="Pepsi Direct",
    True ->>> "15 or 225$ Rev",
    False ->>> IF(H89="Large Format",
        False True -->> VLOOKUP(B89,LF_List,3,FALSE),
        False False -->> IF(H89="Small Format",
            False False True -->> IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B89,OTS_List,2,FALSE)),
            False False False -->> "22")

     -- issue ?
     ,IF(H89="FoodService Format",
       True -->> "-",
       False -->> ""
 )))
```